# Geb/Spock: setting (required: false) on page content in a module not working

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I have a repeating table structure on a page, which looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>some text</td>
  <td>some integer</td>
  <td>empty</td>
  <td>some text</td>
  <td>empty</td>
  <td>contains an input field for the most part, but sometimes it may be blank/radio button/checkbox/etc.</td>
</tr>
```

I have created a module in Geb for modelling the repeated content, which looks like this:

```
class RowModule extends Module {

    static content = {
        cell { $("td", it) }
        description { cell(0).text() }
        rubrikNum { cell(1).text().toInteger() }
        preDefinedValue { cell(3).text() }
        inputField(required: false) { cell(5).$("input") }            
    }
}
```

I have verified that I am able to fetch all rows that have input fields with the code above. However, whenever I encounter a non-input field in the last "td" I am getting the following error:

```
geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: The required page content 'cell - SimplePageContent (owner: modules.RowModule@6fec88c4, args: [5], value: null)' is not present
```

Since I had defined that content as not required, I expected to be able to fetch all cells and those that did not contain an input field to be null or "EmptyNavigator". I am using Geb 0.12.2 and Spock 1.0.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think your problem is, that you you try to access the 5th element of an array which does not exist! something like a indexOutOfBounds exception... the required:false would only work if the 5. cell would be there but without an input element in it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. There was a row in the table which, for some strange reason, had a different structure than the other ones, i.e. the 5th cell did not exist, as you suspected. Thnx for pointing me in the right direction!

Provide your comment above as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct. One additional question: Could I change the content definition for "inputField" to handle that exception, e.g. something like:
`inputField(required: false) { cell(5).$("input") ?: "N/A" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you you try to access the 5th element of an array which does not exist! something like a indexOutOfBounds exception... the required:false would only work if the 5. cell would be there but without an input element in it.